# Icenium navigator.alert not working

Tags: cordova-3, icenium

I'm using Icenium Graphite and cordova v3 and cannot get navigator.notification.alert() to work.

When something happens I want to tell the user using a nice alert, so thought using navigator.notification.alert would work, but nothing appears.

In the code below I get the standard alert box show 'a' then 'b' but not notification alert. Why is this?

Here is my code ...

```
alert("a");
navigator.notification.alert(
                'Saved!',
                function(){},
                'Customer',
                'Done'
            );
alert("b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working ... dismiss function wasn't right.

navigator.notification.alert(
            'Saved!',
            function(){
                //do something
            },
            'Customer',
            'Done'
        );